# Writing python scripts

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a standalone program that would run on a python cmd. This program counts the number of characters in every line of `HumptyDumpty.txt` file, and outputs this to a new file.
Note that the new file needs to contain only the number of characters per line.

Here's  my code:

```
import sys

infilename = sys.argv[1]
outfilename = sys.argv[2]

infile=open(infilename)
outfile=open(outfilename, 'w')
char_=0
for line in infile:
    line.split()
    char_= len(line.strip("\n"))
    outfile.write(str(char_ ))
    print(line,end='')

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The ouput file has only one line, the concatenation of `xyz` instead of

```
x
y
z
```

"\n" doesnt seem to be doing the trick. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no point to either `char_ = 0` or `line.split()`. Your code would work the same if those two lines were simply dropped. You could try to write `str(char_) + '\n'` . Also, calling an int value `char_` is an odd choice. The length isn't a character.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the white space between the words then you should replace them with an empty string.

```
for line in infile:
    nline = line.replace(" ", "")
    nline = nline.strip("\n")
    char= len(nline)
    outfile.write(str(char))
    outfile.write("\n")
    print(line, end='')
    print(char)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.All i needed was the code outfile.write("\n")